# expand macro before using as param for listing in newcommand

Tags: macros, listings

I wanted to create a parametrized macro (using newcommand) for my listings:

It works as long as I use text as input parameter. Once I switch to macros as parameter it doesn't work.

I have the following MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{listings}
\begin{document}
\def\A{name}
\def\C{value}
\newcommand{\paramListing}[4]{
\begin{lstlisting}^^J
#1(#2, #3, #4);^^J
\end{lstlisting}
}

\paramListing{func}{\A}{true}{\C} %prints 'func(A, true, C)', but should be 'func(name, true, value)'
\paramListing{func}{name}{true}{value} %prints func(name, true, value)
\end{document}
```

It produces two lines: one with `func(A, true, C)` (which is not what I wanted) and one with `func(name, true, value)`.
Therefore, I did some research and found that `\expandafter` should do the trick.

However, I don't know how to use it correctly (even with multiple parameters), because I still can't use it with a newcommand that accepts only one Parameter!

For example this MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{listings}
\begin{document}
\def\A{name}

\newcommand{\oneParamListing}[1]{
\begin{lstlisting}^^J
func(#1, true, value);^^J
\end{lstlisting}
}

\expandafter\oneParamListing\A %prints 'func(n, true, value)\name'
\expandafter\oneParamListing{\A} %prints 'func(A, true, value)'
\end{document}
```

which produces the line `func(n, true, C)` (which is the first char of the macro `\A`, so in my opinion it may be the right direction?) and the line `func(A, true, C)` which is also not what I wanted?.

I tried everything with pdfTeX 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.21.

Summarized I have two questions:

- Is `\expandafter` what I need here? If yes, how can I use it?
- Can I use it for macros with more than one parameters? Or do you have another approach here?

Comment: the example works, it prints everything in monospace font

Comment: Indeed, my bad.  I'll delete that comment.  I think you want `\expandafter\oneParamListing\expandafter{\A}`

Comment: thanks, that fixes the second MWE!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Meanwhile I found the answer on my own:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{listings}
\begin{document}
\def\A{name}
\def\C{value}
\newcommand{\paramListing}[4]{
\begin{lstlisting}^^J
#1(#2, #3, #4);^^J
\end{lstlisting}
}

\edef\params{{func}{\A}{true}{\C}}
\expandafter\paramListing\params
\end{document}
```

This prints out `func(name, true, value);` as expected.

Answer (score 0):

It is easy to do real function composition with [`functional`](https://ctan.org/pkg/functional) package. In the following code, `\Value` is a predefined function.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{functional}

\begin{document}

\def\A{name}
\def\C{value}

\PrgNewFunction \paramListing {mmmm} {
\begin{lstlisting}^^J
#1(#2, #3, #4);^^J
\end{lstlisting}
}

\paramListing{func}{name}{true}{value}
\paramListing{func}{\Value\A}{true}{\Value\C}

\end{document}
```

[image]